# Terminate function inside another function on Linux shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm really new to shell scripts and I'm trying to figure out how to terminate a function that uses an infinite loop inside another function.
The code more or less looks like this:

```
finish=1

function1() {
    function2&
    ...
    finish=0
}
function2() {
    while [ $finish==1 ] 
    do
    ...
    done
}
```

And the main part of the script callS only function1. Is there any other way to terminate function2 when function1 finishes? I also tried killing it by id, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A function call in bash will be executed in a subshell. You can store the pid of that subshell and kill it before function1 exits. Like this:

```
function1() {
    function2&
    pid=$!

    ...

    kill "$pid"
}

function2() {
    while true 
    do
        ...
    done
}
```

Comment: Still, function2 is not terminated. I can tell because I'm creating a file inside function2, where I append things every 0.5 seconds, and if I delete it after function1 terminates it keeps re-creating itself.

Comment: Sorry, there was typo. It shoud be `pid=$!`

Comment: You are welcome. Note that the fact that the code runs in a sub shell is also the reason that causes your original attempt to fail. You are changing the value of `$finish` only for the current shell, not for the sub shell.